# ASP.NET Core Web API - JWT Message Handler - No Registered Type Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a JWT Token Handler for my Web API project. The idea is that this API is merely a gateway to other APIs and a token is shared across them all. So when a call is made to my API and I am forwarding the call to another, I want to automatically forward the JWT that was attached to the initial request.

I made a custom MessageHandler as seen below:

```
public class JwtTokenHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;
   public JwtTokenHeaderHandler(HttpContext httpContext)
   {
       this.httpContext = httpContext;
   }
   protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
       HttpRequestMessage request,
       CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       string savedToken = await this.httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
       request.Headers.Add("bearer", savedToken);
       return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
   } 
}
```

Then I registered it as a service in the Startup as below:

```
services.AddTransient<HttpMessageHandler>(p => p.GetRequiredService<JwtTokenHeaderHandler>());

IHttpClientBuilder serviceClientBuilder = services.AddHttpClient<IService, Service>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceURL"));
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<JwtTokenHeaderHandler>();
```

The application runs up until a request is made and then this exception comes up:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Application.API1.JwtTokenHeaderHandler' has been registered.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__4`1.b__4_1(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.g__Configure|0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.LoggingHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder builder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, injecting `HttpContext` directly will cause issues. Use `IHttpContextAccessor` and access the context in the Send method.

```
public class JwtTokenHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public JwtTokenHeaderHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        string savedToken = await accessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        request.Headers.Add("bearer", savedToken);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    } 
}
```

Next `GetRequiredService` throws that exception when the requested service is not registered with the collection so make sure to register the handler with the container

Note

> The handler type must be registered as a transient service.

Reference [`AddHttpMessageHandler<THandler>(IHttpClientBuilder)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.addhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientBuilderExtensions_AddHttpMessageHandler__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IHttpClientBuilder_)

```
services.AddTransient<JwtTokenHeaderHandler>();
```

So that `JwtTokenHeaderHandler` can be resolved when requested from the service provider

```
services.AddTransient<HttpMessageHandler>(p => p.GetRequiredService<JwtTokenHeaderHandler>());
services.AddHttpClient<IService, Service>(client => {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceURL"));
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<JwtTokenHeaderHandler>();
```